# Python script hangs on importing rasterio

Tags: terminal, homebrew, performance, python, import

I'm a recent migrant from Linux to OSX, and the transition so far has been quite smooth, until this particular issue.

On a MacBook Pro with the M1 chip, running Ventura 13.1, and with both Python 3.9 and 3.10, my code just freezes during import.

When I run `python -vv my_code.py`, it consistently hangs on:

```
import 'rasterio._show_versions' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x13a9d9550>
# trying .../.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rasterio/_version.cpython-39-darwin.so
```

At this point the terminal is no longer responsive, and I have to `kill -9 PID` to terminate the process.

Any ideas on what could this be? I've installed both Python versions with `brew install python@3.X`. The virtual environments are created with `python3.X -m virtualenv .venv --python=python3.X` (the Python argument is redundant but I wanted to ensure it uses the correct Python version).

The dependencies (proj, gdal, etc) are installed with `brew` as well and are available and function correctly.

To complicate things further, in the same environment, if I run `python -c "import rasterio"` it works just fine.

Comment: Why are there quotes in the `import` line? Shouldn't it be `import rasterio._show_version`?

Comment: That's just the output from running `python -vv ...`. This import line is also internal to `rasterio`. That is, in the code, I just `import rasterio`.